# Saving a struct in C using Files

Tags: c, file, struct

I am trying to make a programm in C which saves me this kind of struct. First of all, my english isn't the best, but I understand it very well.

The main problem is that I don't know where I can fail, because I am new, and I am sure I am doing this with a lot of errors. I would like to read this .bin later, so I don't know what to do, I would appreciate some help, thanks :)

Here an example of my programm and the struct I want to save:

```
//HERE THE STRUCT//
typedef struct{
   char name[MAX_Nom_Impresora+1];
   int start,end;
} tExample;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){

   ...
   tSave f[4];
   Save(f)
   ....

}    

//HERE THE FUNCTION TO SAVE THE STRUCT//

int Save (tExample f[]){
   FILE *pf;
   char *File="list.bin";
   int counter=0;
   int error=0;

   pf=fopen("File","a");
   if(pf==NULL)
      printf("\n Error.");
   else{
      fwrite(&f, sizeof(f),1, pf);
   }
   return error;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `fopen(File, "a"). Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: look up serialization

Comment: Won't `sizeof(f)` return the size of a pointer? Better to add the number of elements to that function call and use that and `sizeof(tExample)` in the `fwrite`.

Comment: Also before returning from the function you need to close the file. So you need to call `fclose(pf)`. Along with calling `fopen("FILE","a")` will open a file named **FILE** and not **list.bin**

Comment: The file should be opened in binary mode, so it should be `"ab"`, not just `"a"`.

Comment: you can just write or fwrite, but before you do that, you may want to optimize the order of your struct members.  A generic ways is to put largest integral types followed by smallest, followed by a variable length array for a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse structs, pointers to struct and array of structs.

I assume, you wrote `tSave f[4]`, but it should have been `tExample f[4]`. So you try to save an array of 4 structs.

First problem is that in C language, when you pass an array as parameter to a function, you actually pass the address of the first element of the array, and there is no mean in the function to get the size of the array. So you should pass the size of the array along with the array itself :

```
save(f, sizeof(f)/sizeof(tExample));
```

because in the module where the array is declared, the compiler knows the size and you can compute the number of elements, what is not possible in the function `save`.

Next, as you passed a `tExample[]` to function `save`, what you get in the function is an address. So `sizeof(f)` is in fact `sizeof(tExample*)` : the size of a pointer. Your code should be :

```
int Save (tExample f[], int nelts){
   FILE *pf;
   char *File="list.bin";
   int counter=0;
   int error=0;

   pf=fopen("File","a");
   if(pf==NULL)
      printf("\n Error.");
   else{
      fwrite(f, sizeof(tExample),nelts, pf);
   }
   return error;
}
```

Note :

- no `&` before `f` since f is actually an address (the array decayed to a pointer)
- use explicitely the size of the struc
- use explicitely the number of elements that you passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

This is a Posix version that you could adapt to ansi if you replace `open`, `close`, `read` and `write` with `f` prefixed versions and operate on `FILE *` streams instead of file descriptors.

```
static int get_value(const char *path, void *buf,size_t len){ 
   int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); 
   if (fd<0) return fd; 
   len=read(fd,buf,len); 
   close(fd); 
   return len; 
} 
static int set_value(const char *path, void *buf,size_t len){ 
   int fd = open(path, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,0644); 
   if (fd<0) return fd; 
   len=write(fd,buf,len); 
   close(fd); 
   return len; 
}
```

usage:

- `set_value("/path/to/my/struct_file",&my_struct,sizeof(my_struct));`
- `get_value("/path/to/my/struct_file",&my_struct,sizeof(my_struct));`

Answer (score -1):

Change

> sizeof(f)

to

> sizeof(f) * sizeof(tExample)

Also, remember to close the file before the program ends.

Comment: @Jongware You are right, I did a test and the compiler actually complained: "warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'int *' instead of 'int []'".